# Store files in AT45DB161D SPI chip to use them from arduino

Tags: arduino-nano, spi

I am new to this concept but I am wondering if it is possible to store some files on the AT45DB161D dataflash chip. these files must be read by Arduino. I know that I should use a file system and I saw the FatFs library but I don't have any idea how to do that with my Arduino nano.
is it possible to format the chip with Arduino and store files on it?
thank you in advance for your help and sorry about the obvious mistakes.

Comment: It's just a flash chip. Sure, you could run some form of filesystem on it, but that's rarely done in a small MCU environment. Just treat it like a block of memory (EEPROM) and store things at specific addresses. What kind of data do you want to store, anyway?

Comment: .text , .css , .html files 
like the SPIFFS on esp32
how can I store these types of files at specific addresses?
can you explain a bit more.

Comment: There's many ways you could do it. For that sort of data a filesystem would be a simpler interface, sure. I assume you're wanting to run a web server on the Nano?

Comment: I am gonna do it on mega. but currently, I don't have access to one.
sorry, but can you provide me with some examples or documentations to implement the file system format?

Comment: You would probably take the FatFS library and write a "driver" for your flash chip. The FatFS system is modular and allows you to add drivers for new devices reasonably simply (well, simply for an experienced embedded programmer).